# How to write a program that outputs the source code?

Tags: python

> You are asked to write a program that prints the source-code of the above program as its output.
>
> To test your program, you can proceed as follows:
>
> 1. Run your program and save the generated output to a file named `generated.py`
> 2. Run `generated.py` and examine its output.
>
> We assume that your initial Python program is in file `lab3_x.py` the following steps must be run in the PyCharm terminal:
>
> ```
> %python lab3_x.py > generated.py
> %python generated.py
> ```
>
> Notice the output redirection `>`. It causes the output of program `lab3_x.py` to be written to the file `generated.py`. The output of `lab3_x.py` is the python program (source code) that converts stuff.
>   (You may open file `generated.py` with Pycharm and check its contents!)

My questions are as follows:

1. What does `>` do when written in the terminal?
2. Does it has to open a fully working program when `generated.py` is executed in terminal?
3. When I try to `lab3_x.py > generated.py` it opens up a new file named after `generated.py`, but with nothing inside. Why is this?

My code:

```
print('# Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion program\n')
print("fahren = float(input('Enter degrees Fahrenheit: '))")
print("celsius = (fahren - 32) * 5 / 9")
print("print(fahren, 'degrees Fahrenheit equals',")
print("      format(celsius.'.1f'), 'degrees Celsius')")
```

Comment: If the notation > file is appended to any command that normally writes its output to standard output, the output of that command will be written to file instead of the standard output.

Comment: Looks like a homework question, can you show your work and we can help

Comment: I have edited the question. But I mean, it does not really help much.

Comment: Run **python lab3_x.py**. Does it print the correct code? Run **python lab3_x.py > g.py**. Does g.py now contain the correct code? Run **python g.py**. Does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your code, you are using redirection ">" which outputs the code to a file. So your print statements actually print to the python file, which should be executable assuming the print statements result in a correct python file.

So `lab3_x.py > generated.py` will write the print statements onto the python file/